# Mapping an iterator (of a set of maps) to a set on integers

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std, stdmap

I have the following data structure.

```
std::set< std::map<ScanSegment*, bool> > lockRules;
```

I want to map each entry in this structure to a set of users (represented by a set of integers. So I created the following map

`std::map<std::set<std::map<ScanSegment*,bool> >::iterator, std::set<int> > lockRuleUsersMap;`

So that I can directly map the index iterator of each entry in the lockRules set to a set of users.
So far the code compiles. However as soon as I try to fill the map with values I very long compile errors.

```
set<int> users;
for(int i = 1; i < numUsers; ++i){
    users.insert(i);
}
for(set<map<ScanSegment*, bool> >::iterator it = lockRules.begin(); it != lockRules.end(); ++it){

    lockRuleUsersMap[it] = users;
    //Compile error here
    lockRuleUsersMap.insert(make_pair(it,users));
    //also compile error.
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Also I want to read from this map in the following way

```
for(set<map<ScanSegment*,bool> >::iterator xx = lockRules.begin(); xx != lockRules.end(); ++xx){
    map<ScanSegment*,bool> ru = (*xx);
    set<int> users;
    //users = lockRuleUsersMap.at(xx);
    map<set<map<ScanSegment*,bool> >::iterator, set<int> >::iterator lkItr;
    lkItr = lockRuleUsersMap.find(xx);
    if(lkItr != lockRuleUsersMap.end()){
        users = (lkItr)->second;
    }else{
        WRN << "Couldn't find lock rule in the lockRuleUsersMap" << endl;
    }
}
```

Is that correct or also wrong?

Comment: I bet the error you're seeing goes something like "*no operator '<' found which takes operand of type tree_iterator*". That's because std::set::iterator is not comparable.

Comment: yes exactly that. Okay do you have a suggestion to fix that?? should I just not use the iterator?

Comment: It can be fixed by not using non-comparable values as map key or by specifying comparator for key type.

Comment: Yeah, I've just created an Object to encapsulate both rule and users instead. Thanks for the help guys :)